# Laravel Migration create table from existing table

Tags: laravel-5, database-migration

I am working on such application where table audit should perform to make revision of updated records. Let's say for example I have to log each field update in Users update.

I wants to create clone of existing user table by

```
CREATE TABLE users_audit LIKE users;
```

My main question is,
**Is there any alternative way or provision in Laravel migration to create table from existing table ?**

I know we can run raw sql query in migration up/down method using \DB::raw();

But it would be helpful if any helper function available to create table from existing table like, create or table

Comment: maybe you wanna have a look at this https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Comment: yes, @usrNotFound we can use but for just one table I won't interested to add whole library

Comment: you can use `php artisan migrate:generate table1,table2,table3,table4,table5` as many tables as you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, see the below link

[Click this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)

This  statement is used to execute raw queries

```
DB::statement('CREATE TABLE tablename LIKE existingtablename');
```